# Explicitly defined setter not found in assignment expression

Tags: scala, properties

I have a small conundrum when it comes to Scala properties.

Various blogs and tutorials tell me that this:

```
class Something
{
    var foo = 1
}
```

...can be specified as...

```
class Something
{
    private var _field = 1

    def foo = _field
    def foo_(foo: Int) = _field = foo
}
```

This makes perfect sense to me, when doing assignment the compiler looks for a `name_` method. Problem is it doesn't seem to work for me.

In the following real-world code (same thing happens in other classes as well):

```
class Camera
{
  private var _position = Vector2.zero

  def position: Vector2 = _position
  def position_(position: Vector2) =
  {
    // Do boring transforms.
    _position = position // position shadows outer scope so this does work.
  }
}

// ...
val camera = new Camera
camera.position = Vector2(10, 0)
```

I get an error:

> error: value position_= is not a member of Camera
>   camera.position = Vector(10, 0)

Instead I need to call it the following way to actually make it work: `camera.position_(Vector2(10, 0))` which is neither beautiful nor readable.

In other scenarios, for example when trying to have public getters and private setters I faced the same problem.

What am I doing wrong?

*Using scalac 2.8.0 on Java HotSpot VM 1.6*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your setters need to be named `foo_=` and `position_=`.  If you name them `foo_` and `position_` the compiler doesn't recognize them as setters.

Comment: Thank you. I should pay more attention to the error messages :)

Answer (score 5):

The signature to implement is:

```
def position_=(position: Vector2): Unit
```

So you want to correct your code like this:

```
def position_=(position: Vector2) { _position = position }
```

Comment: Thanks! ... sigh, sadly that is rather obvious when I think about it. Can only upvote one so I took the quickest answer.

Comment: Replacing the equals with braces is unnecessary. The compiler will automatically infer `Unit` from the assignment `_position = position`, and automatically give the `position_=` method the correct return type of `Unit`.